# PHP: what's the total length of a $_POST global variable?

Tags: php, post, global-variables, string-length

I was wondering if anybody knows the total length that a post global could be. e.g:

```
$_POST['formInput'] = "hello world, how long can I be?";
```

I am creating a site where someone will enter an unknown amount of chars into a `textarea`, so potentially it could be 2 pages on a word document.

So if anybody knows of any other methods of how I can do this apart from using a `$_POST` global (it can't be saved in a file, as it's important data that I don't want other people to find) - that would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the size limit of a post request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request) this is older by a month, but the other is better posed IMHO

Comment: This directive specifies the number of bytes from 0 (meaning unlimited) to 2147483647 (2GB) that are allowed in a request body. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check your php.ini for `post_max_size`. This is typically about 8mb by default, but if you're on shared-hosting, it could definitely vary.

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 8M
```

You'll have to use `$_POST` if you wish to send large amounts of data to the server. For further study, I'd suggest checking out [POST Method Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) in the documentation.

Comment: Apache has the LimitRequestBody & LimitRequestFieldSize directives too, not always safe to assume it's restricted by just PHP.

Answer (score 9):

`$_POST` is populated from the body of a HTTP-request. Since there are no restrictions on the size of a HTTP-request, there are no restrictions in the protocol layer. However PHP has some limitations on how much input it will read. You can control this with the ini-setting [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Answer (score 4):

Another problem can be the default limit in php.ini for directive max_input_vars (default 1000), not only the post_max_size. If you have e.g. a very large form with thousands of checkboxes the $_POST array will have only 1000 keys.

Comment: This actually solved my problem with a request being a lot less than `post_max_size`, but it hit the `max_input_vars` limit. Thanks!

Comment: Man you saved my day. I only posted about 80kb of data but with > 1000 fields (big form). Arbitrary fields seemed to be missing on side of PHP until I checked what the browser initially posted against what $_POST[] actually contained, and realized that "only" 1000 fields where parsed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some large amount of data sent from the browser to the server, you'll have to use HTTP POST method -- which means the data will be received, on the PHP side, in the `$_POST` superglobal array ; there's not much you can do about that.

The configuration directive [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) defines the maximum amount of data that can be received using the POST method -- you might need to set that to a value higher than the default one, depending on your needs.

And, as said on the documentation of `post_max_size`, the value set for [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) can also have its importance.