# Does $_POST have a size limit?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the size limit of a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request)

Does $_POST when used in conjunction with forms in PHP have a size limit? Obviously there must be some restrictions with $_GET seeing as most browsers will start to complain at ~250 characters (or something like that) and data could be lost, obviously this restraint doesn't apply to $_POST.

I could test it myself but thought it might be quicker to simply ask here. If I had a simple form with a textarea, how much data could I enter before I ran into problems?

Comment: you could google `post size limit` and it would be even faster

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel as a lonewolf developer I thought I'd opt for what I consider to be my daily dose of human interaction via the stackexchange. :D

Comment: @Downvoters ...a bit over the top, it's a perfectly valid question that hasn't been asked that many times (though now I look, granted, a few).

Comment: Don't you have a bit more intelligent question that require some discussion and cannot be solved by five-second googling for the socialization? Your excuse seems weak to me. I'd say it's mere laziness

Comment: Maybe so, but I think I'm allowed the odd spate of laziness given the extensive idiot-proofing that is involved in programming. :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oddly enough, this is the first result when I Google "$_POST limitations"....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That depends on the value of the PHP configuration directive [`POST_MAX_SIZE`](http://php.net/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) which is usually set to 8 MB (~8 million characters).

Answer (score 9):

Yes it has limitation, you can set the limit from several place:

1., in php.ini

```
post_max_size="8M"
```

2., from the .htaccess file, if you have

```
php_value post_max_size 8M
```

3., from php side,

```
ini_set('post_max_size',"8M")
```

Comment: the two last options will only work if overriding is enabled in the server

Answer (score 6):

yes,

you can change limit from php.ini "post_max_size"

Answer (score 1):

It's a PHP ini directive, [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). It defaults to 8MB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's defined in the php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the POST data is regulated by the post_max_size variable (default to 8M)