# How much data, we can send through get and post methods?

Tags: http

I want to know the length or size of data we can send through get and post methods.

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them

Comment: This is a pretty common question. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the HTTP protocol specification but web browsers and servers do impose limits.

Answer (score 1):

There is no defined limit, according to the RFC.

If you are using a web browser for `GET`, then you are generally going to be limited to around 2K for the full URL.

For `POST`, you are unlikely to hit a limit at any practical level.

Of course, there are server-side limits as well...