# javascript character limit for a string sent by post

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, post

I am creating a string variable in javascript and the length of that string could be any.

I am sending this string by jquery post method to a servlet. This servlet writes the string to a file.

I can alert the string anywhere in my javascript and can see the complete string.

But whenever the string length exceeds 5345 characters, then I get "aborted" message in firebug (I assume data is not sent) and no error message is displayed in server's console.
(For chrome, length limit is little more i.e. 5389)

I guess there is a problem in length of the data that is being sent to the servlet. But I wonder, to my knowledge there is no limit to the amount of data sent by post.

I am using jquery's $.post method as below

```
$.post('servlet', function(data) {

});
```

I want to print the error that has occurred while sending data to the servlet. Can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at this question, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request

Comment: I believe that a limit (if there is one) would be based on the particular application server.  What app server are you using? Tomcat? WebLogic? For Tomcat, there is a maxPostSize attribute - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

Comment: I am using jboss server. With help provided from *Abbas* I came to know that there is maxPostsize attribute to be set at jboss. But don't know exactly in which file. Can you help?

Comment: @Abbas and ZackMacomber are most likely spot on, but out of curiosity, what's causing the difference between browsers? Different length in the headers?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the GET method, you are limited to a maximum of 2,048 characters, minus the number of characters in the actual path.

However, the POST method is not limited by the size of the URL for submitting name/value pairs. These pairs are transferred in the request body and not in the URL.