# Best way to transfer decently sized data stream between servers in php

Tags: php, zip, hosting, data-transfer

I have an "offline processing" server which charges me very little for cpu cycles and a "media serving" server which charges me very little for bandwidth.  I have a ~1.3Mb zip file which the offline processing server generates and then sends over to the media serving server to actually host for download.  The way I had been doing this was by having the offline processing server make the file on himself and ftp it over to the other one, but I had to move hosts and now the offline processing server doesn't have the ability to save files to itself.

My first thought was I can make a listening php script on the media serving server and then post the contents to that script which will save it into a zip file.  Unzipped it is ~4.1Mb so would it be a good idea to post this much data?  The second thing I thought of was streams in php... but I didn't know what would be best.

What is the best way for me to move this 4.1Mb of data from one server to the other when I can't save it as a file in the server which generates the data?

Comment: How often do you need to do this processing?

Comment: about once a week and it is on a cron job because of this -- as my underlying dataset changes, this makes a summary for download on a mobile client.

Comment: Off the top of my head, it seems like it's easily small enough to fit in memory to send to the content server... but I'll note that I'm not a big php guy.

Comment: Why do you have to use PHP?  Rsync or FTP are well suited for this kind of task.

Comment: if you have to use php , you can post such amount of data. it's fine. but make sure your media server settings allow it and php doesn't time out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request

Comment: I have to use php because it is a php script talking to the database and doing the processing so the data is in php's memory and can not make it to a file.  Otherwise I would just FTP like I used to but part of the question was specifically that php could not make any files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your host supports it, I might try something like:

```
$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, "Hello, World!"); // create your file
fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

// connect to ftp
ftp_fput($ftp, '/foo', $fp, FTP_BINARY);   

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Very very interesting -- I had never heard of the php://memory before but I will look into that.

Comment: Worst case, you could put everything into a variable (string) and write a thin stream wrapper over it. That would definitely work. (For an ugly example: http://php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  It worked very well but I also have a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488752/string-to-zipped-stream-in-php) you might be able to solve since it is related