# String to Zipped Stream in php

Tags: php, file, stream, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a processing server with my database and a serving database to serve up files with a low bandwidth cost. On the processing server, php is not able to create files so everything must be done with streams and/or stay in memory before being sent over to another server for download.  A few days ago I found out about the stream abstraction with 'php://memory' and that I can do something like

```
$fp=fopen('php://memory','w+');
fwrite($fp,"Hello world");
fseek($fp,0,SEEK_SET);

//make a ftp connection here with $conn_id
$upload = ftp_fput($conn_id,"targetpath/helloworld.txt",$fp,FTP_BINARY);
```

to make the file in memory and then allow me to ftp it over to my other server.  This is exactly what I want, except I also want to zip the data before sending it -- preferably using only native parts of php like ziparchive and not additional custom classes for special stream manipulation. I know that I am very close with the following...

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open('php://memory', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
  $zip->addFromString('testtext.txt','Hello World!');
  $fp = $zip->getStream('test'); if(!$fp) print "no filepointer";

  //make a ftp connection here with $conn_id
  $upload = ftp_fput($conn_id,"targetpath/helloworld.zip",$fp,FTP_BINARY);
} else print "couldn't open a zip like that";
```

The point at which this fails is the call to getStream (which always returns false although I think I am using correctly). It appears that the zip is fine making the file in 'php://memory' but for some reason getStream still fails although perhaps I don't sufficiently understand how ZipArchive makes zips...

How can I go from the string to the zipped filepointer so that I can ftp the zip over to my other server?  Remember I can't make any files or else I would just make the zip file then ftp it over.

**EDIT:** based on skinnynerd's suggestions below I tried the following

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open('php://memory', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
  $zip->addFromString('testtext.txt','Hello World!');
  $zip->close(); 

  $fp = fopen('php://memory','r+');
  fseek($fp,0,SEEK_SET);

  //connect to ftp
  $upload = ftp_fput($conn_id,"upload/transfer/helloworld.zip",$fp,FTP_BINARY);
}
```

This does make a zip and send it over but the zip is 0 bytes large so I don't think that 'php://memory' works the way I thought... it actually fails at the close step -- the $zip->close() returns false which makes me wonder if I can open zips into 'php://memory' at all. Does anyone know what I can try along these line to get the zip?

Comment: It looks like ZipArchive doesn't support saving unless you close. It would need to have a `->save()` method, while keeping the file pointer active for it to work. (You'd then seek to 0 and upload.) I would use `gzencode()` as Parahat Melayev suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be a Zip archive? Since you're trying to save bandwith it could be a gzip too.

```
<?php
 $ftp_credentials = "ftp://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/helloworld.gz";
 $gz = gzencode("Hello World!", 9);
 $options = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true));
 $stream_context = stream_context_create($options);
 file_put_contents($ftp_credentials, $gz, 0, $stream_context);
?>
```

Comment: Yes it could be a gzip even though that will force me to change the decompressing step in some other code so I would prefer if I could get the zip version to work.  I will try to see if I can get the gzip solution and if it is much easier then I may go with that.

Comment: So I didn't know that much about gzip before but it looks like where zip will archive multiple files and folders together the gzip solution simply acts on strings so this will be guaranteed to work since I can already send over a file just fine... I think I will go with this solution.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`$zip->getStream('test')` is getting a stream to extract the file `'test'` from the archive.  Since there's no file `'test'` in the archive, this fails.  This is *not* the function you want to use.

As you said, what you want to do is send the finished archive to the ftp server.  In this case, you would want to close the zip archive, and then reopen `php://memory` as a normal file (using `fopen`) to send it.

I don't know, but you may also be able to use `$zip` as a resource directly, without having to close and reopen the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried some ways with fopen but in the end I think I will go with a gziped string solution.

Answer (score 2):

And I think you can try create a stream pipe directly from ftp server

```
<?php
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open('ftp://user:password@ftp.host.com/upload/transfer/helloworld.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE)) 
    {
        $zip->addFromString('testtext.txt','Hello World!');                         
        $zip->close();
    } 
    else 
        print "couldn't open zip file on remote ftp host.";
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't create the zip file on the server.

Comment: I also tried this but I wasn't able to get it to work... again it failed at the close step not the open if that means anything.