# PHP ZIP archive gets copied to root before user selects save location

Tags: php, header, download, zip

Looks like adding

unlink($filename);

to the bottom seems to fix it:

=====================================================================

So what I am trying to do is create a zip file from 2 strings and then send some headers that tell the browser to open a "save as" dialog box and download the zip file.

It works fine but when the user clicks the download link a copy of the zip file gets copied to the root of the php folder where the php script is when the "save as" dialog box pops up. Anybody know why this happens? I think the problem may be in the headers. I just want 1 copy to be saved where the user specifies.

```
$string1 = "Some data Some data Some data Some data Some data Some data";
$string2 = "Some data Some data Some data Some data Some data Some data";

$filename = "test.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
   exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}


$zip->addFromString("string1.html", $string1);
$zip->addFromString("string2.html", $string2);


$zip->close();


header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

clearstatcache();

header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);


?>
```

Comment: `gets copied to the root of my server when the "save as" dialog box pops up` really root of your server? or the root of the box where the webbrowser runs?

Comment: it gets saved to my php folder where the php script is. But a user can still save a copy to their own location.

Comment: Is there maybe a way to delete right after the user downloads a copy?

Comment: Actually adding unlink($filename); to the bottom seems to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's what `open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)` does... I'd do this:

```
->open($tempfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'yourzip_'), ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)
 ....
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
 ...
 header("Content-Length: ".filesize($tempfile));
 readfile($tempfile);
 unlink($tempfile);
```

Note that your 'test.zip' filename only needs to be in the header, you can call your tempfile anything you like.

Comment: Ok.....so do I need the "if" statement or do i just write:

$zip->open($tempfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'yourzip_'), ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)

Comment: Yep, although you most likely will never encounter an error, there _are_ malconfigured systems without temp dirs, or temp dirs you aren't allowed to write to.

Comment: @chiminage note that your edit to the question (_adding `unlink` to the button seems to fix it_), you still have race conditions: with a fixed `open($filename)`, 2 simultaneous users can get wrong data.

Comment: Well, as long as the sysadmins aren't morons it won't happen... But you could create your own temp dir & make it writable of course, preferably outside the document root.

Comment: Will this work the same if I am writing HTML data as one of the strings? So if one of the strings is $string1 = $_POST["html_data"] ?

Comment: That doesn't make _any_ difference for this bit. It doesn't care what strings you add.

Comment: @Wrikken.....Thanks for all your help...if you have a second can you take a look at the question i posted here...Im having trouble getting my HTML string to write to the Zip archive. The text string writes fine but the html file is blank...not sure why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301323/

Answer (score 0):

I think the file is getting saved on your server as soon as you call `$zip->open()`.

I'm not super familiar with the way ZipArchive works but if it requires that you call the `open()` method in order to work, you could try using the `php://memory` protocol as described in this question:

[String to Zipped Stream in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488752/string-to-zipped-stream-in-php)

Note: The above link is only relevant in terms of how to use the `php://memory` protocol.