# PHP pass HTML string to create ZIP archive

Tags: php, html, download, zip

So I am trying to create a Zip file from 2 strings. 1 is a html string, the other is plain text. So far I only seem to get the text string to work correctly but the file thats supposed to be HTML is just a blank file. Any idea why?

```
$string1 = $_POST["html_string"];
$string2 = "Some data Some data Some data Some data Some data Some data";


$filename = "test.zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive();


if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)==TRUE) {

    $zip->addFromString("string1.html", $string1);
    $zip->addFromString("string2.txt", $string2);
    $zip->close();
}


header("Content-Type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");

//clearstatcache();

header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
unlink($filename);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does `echo $_POST["html_string"];` show?

Answer (score 2):

Tryed your code replacing

```
$string1 = $_POST["html_string"];
```

with

```
$string1 = '<html>

<title></title>

</html>';
```

and worked.

Are you sure $_POST["html_string"] is not empty? Add var_dump($_POST); to see if there is some data or update your code adding a check at the begining.

```
if (empty($_POST["html_string"]))
{

echo 'html_string is empty';
exit;
}
```