# Max size of post data in http

Tags: http, post, size

Is there any limit in terms of amount of data that can be sent with HTTP POST ?

I have seen in some emails there is limit of 25 MB or 20 MB for attachments..,but I think they are imposed by the server or application...

In terms of plain HTTP is there any limit....

Also, is there any limit in terms of size of value of a field as well?

And why large values in hidden fields are not a good thing, or is it?

Comment: Partial duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this one in ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/q/151090 where there are other very good answers too.

Answer (score 9):

Post data limits are set by the application on the server that the file is uploaded to.  Just to give you something concrete to think about, here is a discussion on about max_filesize from the php manual, http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php .  Many websites use php's builtin functions and that link describes how the upload function is setup by default.  Of course the defaults are different for each web platform such as if they use a ruby on rails or python based one.