# Call RESTFul API - HTTP POST Limit

Tags: iphone

I call a RESTFul API but the HTTP POST got a limit because am sending JSON over and it is cutting off part of the JSON requests... What can I do to resolve this problem?

RESTFUl API is written in PHP and accept the JSON in a variable via HTTP POST requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the size of request accepted from PHP on your server.

Look this discussion [What is the size limit of a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request)