# How to send large data using POST method?

Tags: html

How do you send large amount of data using POST method?

I heard that post method default is 8M now what if you exceed that size? How would you send a plain text to the server?

Comment: The post max size is what you have set it to in your server configuration.

Comment: There are several other options. What is your server side language and do you have access to the server? Where does the data come from? Is it from a user or generated by some script?

Comment: @Oded I am not saving a file but inserting a 20K character in db.

Comment: @feela is there other way to do this?

Comment: @while yes I have access to the server, i am using mysql, i am trying to send to a 20K character to the table and it is user generated.

Comment: I think multiple ajax calls is the best solution in that case as stated in the answers below. Just split the input in equal parts and send through several ajax requests in the background.

Answer (score 9):

A good answer by **David**:

> The url portion of a request (GET and POST) can be limited by both the
>   browser and the server - generally the safe size is 2KB as there are
>   almost no browsers or servers that use a smaller limit.
>
> The body of a request (POST) is normally* limited by the server on a
>   byte size basis in order to prevent a type of DoS attack (note that
>   this means character escaping can increase the byte size of the body).
>   The most common server setting is 10MB, though all popular servers
>   allow this to be increased or decreased via a setting file or panel.
>
> *Some exceptions exist with older cell phone or other small device browsers - in those cases it is more a function of heap space reserved
>   for this purpose on the device then anything else.

[What is the size limit of a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request)

**NOTE**: 2MB of data by URL means 2097152 Char in one request.

Also if you want to send more data you can use **multipal ajax request**

Comment: when i check the php.ini the post_max_size is 128M but when i try to post a 20K character it doesn't allow the post method?

Comment: its because of your browser Restriction on post data size check : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427

Comment: now if you really want to send all that data you have one option as multipal ajax request

Answer (score 1):

Upload the file, as you'll probably get time outs if there are interruptions.

Are you sending to a PHP script? If so you may need to increase upload size in php.ini

Search for `upload_max_filesize`

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the ini.php change the value

```
post_max_size
```

to

```
20M
```

---

from 8M you will be able to achieve what you want