# how to send large data using post method in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, csv, http-post

I am trying to process large csv data in nodejs at server side, but as node is single threaded cpu uses goes to 100%. I could not find any solution so that it does not consume much time. So I have decided to process the data on client side and then send it to server and then save it into database. The data might be about 20 to 30 MB. Is it possible or if possible is it good practice to send this much data over http. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475116/how-to-send-large-data-using-post-method) question but could not find it helpful.

Comment: FYI, you could also use child processes in node.js to process your CSV saving the main node.js process for normal request processing.  This is typically how you handle CPU-heavy work in node.js.  I'd also wonder if you're properly using async I/O for your data.

Answer (score 1):

To know the limit of post http request,

It rather depends on the web server and web browser:

Internet explorer All versions 2GB-1
Mozilla Firefox All versions 2GB-1
IIS 1-5 2GB-1
IIS 6 4GB-1

Please look for following link

[Is Http POST limitless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/is-http-post-limitless)

Also, use techniques like data chunks for server side to recive heavy data.