# how to send image base64 to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, base64, image-uploading

I used base64 encoded to display image dynamically (by select image).

```
<img style="width: 412px;" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhwAAAAXAAACH5BAEAAPwALA
```

How to send image to a server? by $.ajax() and without postback.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', //or get
    url : 'urlToMyServer.aspx',
    data: { img : $('img').attr('src') }
});
```

If the B64 is'nt really, really long, just send it the regular way ?

Comment: `data: $('img').attr('src')` this won't work. `data` accepts an object or a query string.

Comment: @iMoses it accepts arbitrary string, which jQuery will send literally as POST request body

Comment: @iMoses - sending a string is'nt a problem, but objects are actually easier to understand in this case I think, so I've edited it.

Comment: If so than how do I fetch it on the server side? What's the name of my post variable? As far as I know, if you wanna use a string it should be formated as a query string, such as: `data: 'img=' + $('img').attr('src')`

Comment: @iMoses depends on the language/platform, in php you would do `$requestBody = file_get_contents( "php://input");`

Comment: @iMoses - it accepts anything, even just an array, jQuery creates the querystring or whatever it needs to send. Not really very good at C#. so how you'd capture that in ASP I'm not sure of.

Comment: If you pass a string, jQuery will not do anything to it, and you have to parse raw request body manually on the server

Comment: Ok, you're right :) Though you have to admit it's much more readable to use `$requestBody = $_POST['img']` as well as indicating the name of the variable on the client side.

Comment: @adeneo-you says:it accepts anything.i asked you?what's string length?

Comment: @hamed hossani http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request

Comment: Usually post requests are somewhere around 2 megabyte, but it's a server setting, so if you have enough memory you could set it to 2 gigabyte for that matter!

Comment: tanks to all,How to upload my image to a server?