# base64 code send to server by java script, ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I am using Html5, Java script, ajax and java. I am uploading a image from desktop to the crop and after the crop it is showing in bootstrap modal in same page. But i am not getting URL for this Image, I am getting some Base64 code and when i am sending this base64 code than it is not working.

> I seen this post but i did not get any solution from this link:
>   [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905681/how-to-send-image-base64-to-server)

This code for static image, Showing first time.

My code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="img-container">
         <img src="../assets/img/picture.jpg" alt="Picture">
    </div>
<div class="modal fade docs-cropped" id="getCroppedCanvasModal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="getCroppedCanvasTitle" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
 <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" id="download"  download="cropped.png" href="javascript:void(0);">Upload</a>

 </div>
</div>
```

Java script Code:

```
     (function () {
            var $image = $('.img-container > img');
            var $download = $('#download');
        $('#getCroppedCanvasModal').modal().find('.modal-body').html(result);
                    if (!$download.hasClass('disabled')) {
                        $download.attr('href', result.toDataURL());
                        //console.log("*****************"+result.toDataURL());
                        var swapUrl = result.toDataURL();
                        console.log("*******" + swapUrl);

//                        document.getElementById('replaceMe').src = swapUrl;

                        $('#download').click(function () {
                            var b = result.toDataURL();
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/sf/p/customizeText",
                                type: 'GET',
                                data: b,
                                success: function (response) {
                                    console.log("999999999999999999999999999999999----------------" + b)
                                },
                                complete: function (response) {

                                },
                                error: function (response) {

                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
}
```

I am assign result.toDataURL() into variable b. But it is showing some base64 code.
How i am send this image to server.

I am giving one snippet.
[image] 
 Please give me some idea achieve to this solution.

Comment: When you have the base64 encoded data of your image, you can re-create the image serverside. Just send your Base64 data with the rest of the data to the server and recreate it there using (if php) base64_decode(base64) and imagecreatefromstring(decoded_Base64_data)

Comment: What serverside language are you using .. PHP ?

Comment: I am using advance java

Comment: Does this previous thread help you with creating your image from base64 server side ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506428/convert-base64-string-to-image-in-java .. First step anyways is to just receive the base64 encoded image string serverside, and from there re-create the image from that string ..

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can check this solution also

Javascript code

```
    var base64before = document.querySelector('img').src;
    var base64 = base64before.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    var httpPost = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var path = "your url";
    var data = JSON.stringify(base64);

    httpPost.open("POST", path, false);
    // Set the content type of the request to json since that's what's being sent
    httpPost.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    httpPost.send(data);
```

This is my Java code.

```
    public void saveImage(InputStream imageStream){
    InputStream inStream = imageStream;

    try {
        String dataString = convertStreamToString(inStream);

        byte[] imageBytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(dataString);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
        // write the image to a file
        File outputfile = new File("/Users/paul/Desktop/testkey/myImage.png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }



  static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
  }
```