# export to excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

I want to use javascript, to export the html table to excel. I used below script. Its working fine. Since few cells have special characters, I have escaped them. However, rows and contents after this special characters cell are not downloading. Please help. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){      
    $("#exportToExcel").click(function() {  
        var data='<table border="1" class="csstable">'+$("#myTable").html().replace(/^[a-zA-Z!”$%&’()*\+,\/;\[\\\]\^_`{|}~<>]+$/gi, '')+'</table>';
                $('body').prepend("<form method='post' action='exporttoexcel.php' style='display:none' id='ReportTableData'><input type='text' name='tableData' value='"+data+"' ></form>");
         $('#ReportTableData').submit().remove();
         return false;
    });

});
</script>



<?php  
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".date('d-m-Y').'-'.date("H:i:s").'-'."myfile.xls");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

echo strip_tags($_POST['tableData'],'<table><th><tr><td>');  
?>
```

Comment: maybe escaping is not enough.... how about doing encodeURIComponent on the values instead?

Comment: Are escape characters syntax is correct? I'm poor at regex. I tried to use URI,but no data will be downloaded. But excel sheet will be populated.

Comment: I found the error. Its with Regex. If I'm using single quote ('), then only its giving problem. Rest every characters downloaded. Plz help to escape this single quote. I tried a lot, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/9zaH7/

1. takes table html, wraps in new table - this part seems not to be needed, but maybe you need to remove the styling/class?
2. escapes the complete table to the form text field.

   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#exportToExcel").click(function() {

   ```
       var data='<table border="1" class="csstable">'+$("#myTable").html()+'</table>';
       data=escape(data);
               $('body').prepend("<form method='post' action='exporttoexcel.php' style='display:block' id='ReportTableData'><input type='text' name='tableData' value='"+data+"'></form>");

        return false;
   });});
   ```

Comment: This problem is fixed, since I escaped the single quote charater with double quote. This works fine for certian amount of data. If I want to export more than 10000 rows, then its giving error inside the downloaded excel file.Please help, how to get larger data.

Comment: probably you need to set a maxRequestLength in web.config.... or whats relevant for your system (don't know php) - maybe this article? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request

Comment: Thanks Steen.. I'll check and post the status. Keeping  finger crossed ;)