# How does window.open(data:application) Export to Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

Trying to search for a way to send an HTML table to Excel, I came across ***[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWAJ7/2054/)***

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#whatever').html());
```

I was surprised to find out it was just that simple and I was wondering if anyone could explain how this works. The documentation for window.open doesn't appear to list an explanation under msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453415.aspx or mozilla developer network https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

It could be that I'm not phrasing my question correctly that's preventing me from finding an answer, but I guess I'm just curious how I can utilize this in the future to export html to excel and other file formats or if I shouldn't touch it(for instance if it's something that was abandoned and should never be used)

I've also looked at several other posts such as [JavaScript table export to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710405/javascript-table-export-to-excel) and [export to excel using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982872/export-to-excel-using-javascript) and though they may answer the questions, I'm asking specifically about what's happening in the above code because it's so simple and concise.

Comment: this will help with your googling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs

Comment: excel opens HTML files with tables as though they were xls files. window.open() display an HTML page, or downloads non-html pages, which is what jQuery tells the popup it has. the jQuery part simply grabs the html of a table. put them all together, and viola.

Comment: excellent. thank you gentleman