# cordova plugin pass base64 string size limit ? : Android

Tags: java, android, plugins, cordova

Using cordova 2.6.0. And a plugin on the android side.

The issue is that i am trying to pass a base-64 string  to my plugin, but there was an error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Tried to debug it and found that there is a **mismatch in size** between the sent base-64 string from javascript(from cordova.exec function) and the received plugin in java.
The size of the string in java is nearly half of the original string.

> Verified the same by pasting both strings in a browser. Browser displayed the image for the javascript part and not for the java part.

Also tried to stringify the JSON object (containing the base-64 string), and pass it to the plugin. But then also there is a mismatch in size(same as above).

Have tried for different images, receiving the same result.

> A solution is to break the sent base-64 string to some parts and use it again on the java/plugin side.

I am receiving the arguments in a JSON Array, there might be a limit in that maybe. M not sure.

Hope some one can help and tell where am I going wrong.

Comment: this is just a guess... but maybe your post size is to large

Comment: @PhilippSander : Yes the size is large. I sent a small sized base-64 string, and received it fully in the plugin. Thats why asked the question, how large is too large ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request

Comment: @PhilippSander : Sorry for replying so late, thanks for the effort man!! But now m pretty sure that its using something GET like instead of POST like, to call the PLUGIN method.(as GET has a limit on payload size and POST does not)

Comment: okay... my fault... but good i got you on the right track :)