# maximum length of post and get variable name

Tags: php, html, ajax

What is maximum post and get variable limit?
I am calling a page in ajax and it goes on fail function

```
 $.ajax("data_valid.php?duplicateaccountname=a")
        .done(function(data) {
            alert(data+"data");
         })
        .fail(function() { 
            alert("error");
            dup = "error";
 });
```

but this is working

```
            $.ajax("data_valid.php?dup=a")
        .done(function(data) {
            alert(data+"data");
         })
        .fail(function() { 
            alert("error");
            dup = "error";
         });
```

is there is any variable name limit?

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2659995/1207346)

Comment: This should not at all be a problem. GET parameters are often that long. Is it a server error you get? Or a PHP error? You can inspect that using e.g. Chrome Inspector or Firebug...

Comment: possible duplicate of [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Answer (score 4):

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

in your php.ini, there's a variable like `post_max_size`, `max_get_size`

you might be using the suhosin patch which has its own max query string/post/get/..... variables in its config.

php.ini:

`post_max_size = 8M #8Mb is 8000000 bytes, 1 byte = 1 ascii character`

suhosin.ini:

```
;suhosin.get.max_array_depth = 50
;suhosin.get.max_array_index_length = 64
;suhosin.get.max_name_length = 64
;suhosin.get.max_totalname_length = 256
;suhosin.get.max_value_length = 128000
;suhosin.get.max_vars = 100
;suhosin.post.max_array_depth = 100
;suhosin.post.max_array_index_length = 64
;suhosin.post.max_name_length = 64
;suhosin.post.max_totalname_length = 256
;suhosin.post.max_value_length = 1000000
;suhosin.post.max_vars = 1000
;suhosin.request.max_array_depth = 100
;suhosin.request.max_array_index_length = 64
;suhosin.request.max_totalname_length = 256
;suhosin.request.max_value_length = 1000000
;suhosin.request.max_vars = 1000
;suhosin.request.max_varname_length = 64
;suhosin.upload.max_uploads = 25
;suhosin.session.max_id_length = 128
```

Comment: don't forget about `max_input_vars` in PHP itself

Answer (score -1):

Answered here:
[What is the size limit of a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request)

And here:
 [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Comment: The poster is talking about max length of a variablename (e.g. duplicateaccountname in the URL), not about the size of the complete POST or GET requests...