# Request Entity Too Large on godaddy server in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have codeigniter application in which i have to upload 11 images using base64 string, i works properly on localhost but not working on server , if images small then it works.

```
 The requested resource
 KnSD67KDqyt9QdeatGg--
does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I have increased post_max_size to 128 MB

Comment: You have increased `post_max_size` option, but error message tells you tha is `GET` request used. Max size of url is approximately 8kB or even less (could be 2kB) which is roughly 2000 characters. It depends on server and PHP sets. Check answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724270/max-size-of-url-parameters-in-get), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107364/maximum-length-of-post-and-get-variable-name) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/base64-encoded-image-size).

Comment: but i used post method.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896644/request-entity-too-large#answer-10148191) (with useful links).