# Request $_POST about 15.000 character?

Tags: php

i have a form and need to display POST variable from form, about 15 000 character, but i cannot echo this POST variable. it is blank
how can i do send POST data as above?

Comment: Can you show us your code? It's hard to find any errors you've made when we can't see what you've tried.

Comment: Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2364875/1501051 there is limit of PHP POST

Comment: @Echo OP's talking about 15k characters. that's something less than 1 MB. I doubt there's a limit hit.

Comment: thank, it 's html code, i copy all html code of a site

Answer (score 0):

try to alter your .htaccess file

```
php_value post_max_size 1M
```

1MB should be plenty to handle 15k Bytes ...

Comment: By default [`post_max_size`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) is set to `8M`. `15k bytes` is only `0.0143051 megabytes`. This is likely not the problem.

Comment: thank, it 's html code, i copy all html code of a site