# Can’t POST huge json data to PHP server with Jquery ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I am trying to post some variables to PHP server via json. One of this variable contains huge string. When I post data all other variable get posted successfully but one that contains huge string remains undefined.

If I make content of that variable sort, then its running fine.

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          data:{name:”aaa”,age:”aaaaa”,detail:”huge string”},
          async:false
        }).done(function( data ) {
            alert(data);
          }).fail(function() {
           $.notify("Cannot connect to server", "error");
        });
```

Comment: How huge? Maybe check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request

Comment: Lines? How long would such a line be? 5 bytes? 500 bytes? (Basically, we need the total length of the string)

Comment: Is this your real code? Do you escape the string?

Comment: @GôTô i guess it is an string encoding issue too

Comment: okay, let me tell u fact.
i am sending javascript code to server. it can be in MBs. but for now i am testing it for around 900kb. i put javascript in json variable

Comment: @user3326391 Any reason to set it synchronous?!

Comment: nope, but i tried. it's not make any difference. problem remain same

Comment: @user3326391 But have you tried: `detail:encodeURIComponent(”huge string”)` ?!

Comment: i tried both escaped and not escaped . but problem is still there.

Comment: just tried encodeURIComponent(”huge string”) .. not working :(

Comment: Any chance we can see an online example?!

Comment: is your PHP hardened with Suhosin-Patch ? If yes: try again after desactivating it.

Comment: sorry guys, i still can't detect problem in my code, but i made same sample code in new project as per your demand @A. Wolff. but it's working perfectly :P. i thought may be probem with codeigniter framework so i tried same sample code with codignirer also and it's also working completely. so i don't know how to show a problem :(. 
any way,.. i will find it out, thank you all

Comment: finally got answer.
and problem is XSS filter in codeigniter.
just disable global_xss_filtering and it's works fine :). thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

please check your php.ini setting for directive

```
post_max_size
```

and try to increase like as below

```
ini_set('post_max_size' '20m')
```