# Objective-c upload to database using script

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode

I am about to develop an application for the iOS devices, that will need to store information in a database on the web. For previous projects, i would just have PHP scripts, and my application would run those scripts and passing in the stuff to upload as _GET parameters, like this:

http://example.com?name=George&contents=iWillBePutIntoDB

However, this is not possible for my next project, as it will contain rather large amount of text, and i could exceed the maximum allowed length of a URL.

So, how do i go about doing this? I cannot access the MySQL database directly from my app, since my shared hosting provider doesn't allow it due to security reasons. So i can only access it using PHP scripts that are stored directly on the server.

In short: How do i upload large amount of text to a MySQL database that doesn't allow access from anywhere except files on the server itself (PHP scripts)?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious way would be using `POST`, instead of using `GET`.

But take it into your considerations that [post is not without its limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request).

Comment: How would i be able to do this from Xcode? Using get i would just put it in the URL http://example.com?lala=tada but i don't think POST works the same way?

Comment: How do you already create get requests? There should probably be a functionality symmetric to that.

Comment: Not really, but i discovered i had to use NSURLConnection to make it! Thanks guys. I honestly didn't think POST requests were possible outside of the PHP script. Another thing learned today :)