# POST limit in Chrome, Safari, not FireFox

Tags: php, post, limit

I'm doing a simple POST via a form to another PHP page.

In Chrome and Safari, the content appears to always be trimmed down to **524kb**, though it works in Firefox.

It's too low to be any of my PHP limits, which are all in the MBs. No LimitRequestBody set in Apache.

I would think that one browser working and two not rules out some kind of firewall rule.

Any other ideas on what to check?

Simple form, value gets filled in by angular. I can verify it is there in its full length on submission:

```
<form method="POST" action="/forcedownload/index.php">
    <input ng-hide="true" type="text"   name="options[filename]" value="{{download.options.filename}}" />
    <input ng-hide="true" type="text"   name="options[filetype]" value="{{download.options.filetype}}" />
    <input ng-hide="true" type="text"   name="data"              value="{{download.data}}" />
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" ng-click="checkStringLength(download.data,result)" value="Download as CSV" ng-hide="!showPart" />
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Need code.  Maybe you are doing something wrong and Firefox is "fixing" it.

Comment: don't forget the webserver as well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2364875/3367343. Also, out of curiousity, what type of data are you posting?

Comment: It's JSON data. Reviewing link now, thx

Comment: I def saw that post. It is far too low to by any of those PHP limits, I've checked those. Its one field, so can't be input_vars.

Comment: How do you know that "the content appears to always be trimmed down to 524kb," as you mentioned?

Comment: @thohl 1st - it fails to be parsed by json_decode, 2nd - echoing the JSON shows it truncated compared to what is in field on submission, 3rd - the data comes from a mysql db, and different criteria produce different strings, but all of the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the code, the input type I was using was "text" (and I was hiding it w/ angular), instead of just using a hidden.

text fields always have a default allowed character limit of 524288.

doh.