# PHP not receiving all POST data

Tags: php

I have a *really* long form, which is basically a sign up for a college.  And it's been working fine, although for some reason now I am not able to receive the POST data for the form anymore.  I seem to receive all the variables, expect for the 'SUBMIT' button, which is what I look for to find out that it's posted.

It's a sliding form, meaning that it's about 450px high and it is split up into different 'pages', and at the bottom of each page there is `previous`, `save for later`, and `next` buttons.  The `previous` and `next` activate jQuery functionality which slides the form left or right.  The `save for later` button is a submit button which puts any received data into the database for retrieval later.  The HTML for these buttons is:

```
<input type='button' class='previous' value='Previous'>
<input type='submit' class='saveforlater' name='saveforlater' value='Save For Later'>
<input type='button' class='next' value='Next'>
```

All three of these buttons work fine, if I test the receiving of `saveforlater` in PHP like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['saveforlater'])) {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

It works every time.

However, right at the end of the form I have this:

```
<input type='button' class='previous' value='Previous'>
<input type='submit' class='next send' name='sendapplication' value='Send Application'>
```

And It used to work, but I cannot figure out what I've changed in order to stop it working.  If I `var_dump($_POST)`, I get all the other variables, except for this button.

So if I try to:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendapplication'])) {
```

I get nothing. NOTHING! I don't know why :(.  It's such a simple thing and it's frustrating me.

Comment: Are you using 2x <input type='submit'> in the same form?

Comment: @valicu2000 Yes, there are lots multiple submit buttons, but only one `sendapplication`.

Comment: have you specified method as post

Comment: @Hudixt Yes - the form tag is: `<form action='/enrol' method='POST' id='enrolform' enctype='multipart/form-data'>`

Comment: @Chud37 Try clicking this button and see if `var_dump` or `debug()` returns this variable.
For submit buttons inside `<form>`, only submit buttons clicked will be setted as $_POST variable.

Comment: @bcesars Yes, I have tried clicking this button and it does not show up in the var_dump.  I haven't looked at `debug()`

Comment: Have you tried to use the same name for the submit buttons? I'm looking at this example: http://salman-w.blogspot.ro/2008/10/multiple-submit-buttons-on-html-forms.html

Answer (score 2):

If you click this button, you will see with `var_dump` or `debug()` returns this variable.

For submit buttons inside `<form>`, only buttons clicked will be setted as $_POST variable with its value.

Answer (score 1):

Your input should have the attribute name. Your html should look like

```
<input type='button' class='previous' name='previous' value='Previous'> 
<input type='submit' class='saveforlater' name='saveforlater' value='Save For Later'>
<input name='saveforlater' type='button' class='next' value='Next'>
```

Your php should look like in /enrol

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

How many fields are there in your form??
I think it is the problem due to size of limited post request. It is the problem of server configuration.
If you want to control it refer following link

[What is the size limit of a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a HTML form to send the data and a localhost server, your attribute action needs to have the PHP file directory on the server.