# Add a Large Byte array to Post request paramter in Rest Api C#

Tags: c#, rest, api

I have a Post method in a regular post Api

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Postt([FromBody]Parameter parameter)
{

}

public class Parameter
{
    public DateTime ValueDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] Blob { get; set; }
}
```

When Blob Is too large (read from a binary file ) I may receive null, and ModelState is in invalid state.

Any Guess or altenative ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959442/the-maximum-size-of-object-that-can-be-passed-as-parameter-to-post-method

Comment: Problem is only blob is filtered not the hole objet. I may receive {
ValueDate: <value>
Blob: null
}