# Java HttpUrlConnection don't read full response body

Tags: java

I can read full response body (big JSON data, more than 400,000 chars) few times, but after 5-6 times my response is not full.

Here's my code of getting response:

```
        URL address = new URL("https://myurl.com/");
        HttpURLConnection Connection = (HttpURLConnection)address.openConnection();

        Connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        Connection.setRequestProperty("accept-language", "en-US");
        Connection.setRequestProperty("user-agent", UserAgent);

        Connection.setRequestProperty("cookie", cookies);

        Connection.setUseCaches(false);
        Connection.setDoInput(true);
        Connection.setDoOutput(true);

        if (Connection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        { 
            String Response = new String();
            InputStream is = Connection.getInputStream();
            int ch;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while (( ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char) ch);
            }
            Response = sb.toString();
            is.close();
        }
```

In my original code after `is.close()`, it is just lot of JSON parsing from Response string

Comment: Why do you read the response body byte by byte?

Comment: I'm beginner and I found that way to read response and it worked, so I used that. Can you post some better ways? Thanks

Comment: Hint: I Java variable names don't start with a capital letter. Use `connection` and `response` as variable names.

Comment: OK, but I guess it won't resolve my problem

Comment: Try any of the `copy` methods of [`IOUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) to copy the `InputStream` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: What do you mean by "my response is not full?"

Comment: Full response is json data, so it looks like: { "name":"value" } Not full like that:  { "name":"va     - It just is not full response body. Original body is soo long, so few thousands of characters are "out"

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be your real code because `Response` is scoped to the `if`. Posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help.

Comment: @xehpuk It's not my real code, but it presents how my code works, so have you any ideas how to fix my problem?

Comment: Maybe you are hitting a limit on the size of the request.  Here's an answer about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request

Comment: @gregbert I don't think so. Why can I grab first 5 responses, but 6th would be cutted? First response is much bigger than next ones

Comment: No, not with the code you provided.

Comment: @xehpuk My original code has just parsing from Response string after is.close(), but I think it's useless information.

Comment: How about your `Connection` variable?  Are you reinitializing that every time you hit the endpoint? What, if anything, do you do if it's not an 200 response?  Is the partial response what you are expecting up to the point it is cut off?

Comment: @gregbert Yes, I'm reinitializing that variable everytime I send request. My function supports just 200 response. Sorry, but I don't understand your 3rd question.

Comment: Can you write up a [MCVE] of this, including a url to your actual data? There is no way anyone can help you with this by making guesses about something that isn't even the code you're running and they can't try themselves.

Comment: Did you checked the response of this query on a browser, to check if yuo get everything ? There is a limit in the response length like _gregbert_ said

Comment: As a debugging option, try hitting the endpoint with postman ( https://www.getpostman.com/ ) and see if you get the same response after 5 calls. Or just in your browser since it's a GET