# HTTP 414 On Post Request- Me or My Shared Host?

Tags: php, angularjs, http, post, get

I am sending a post request using Angular `$http` with a request URI between 10,000 and 11,000 characters to an Apache (shared-hosting) server.

The server rejects my connection attempt, saying `HTTP 414 Request-URI Too Large`

My question is, why is this happening at a POST request?

According to these two posts:

1. [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)
2. [What is the size limit of a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request)

The 8192 limit the server is telling me about should only apply to GET requests, unless I am misunderstanding something?

So am I doing something wrong or is the shared host misconfigured?

Because it is shared hosting, I don't have access to Apache configuration files.

Assuming I can't get around a weird POST limit on the server, how can I send this large request to a PHP script? Do I have to take advantage of `SESSION` to store, for example, the order JSON on a first `$http` and then combine this `SESSION` data with the rest of a second `$http` to get the complete order?

Does that make sense?

My POST request:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://www.example.com/placeanorder',
        params: {
            order: angular.toJson($scope.order),
            orderProperties: angular.toJson($scope.Oproperties),
            token: token,
            totalCost: $scope.totalPrice,
            shippingCost: $scope.shippingCost,
            shippingProperties: angular.toJson($scope.shippingProperties)               
        }
    })
```

Comment: I don't know the angular framework too well, but I'm 99% confident that you are sending all this data in the URL (just like a GET request) instead of in the body, where it should be with POST.

Comment: @Evert Oh dear, you appear to be right!

Comment: So... I use `data` instead of `params`?