# When the data I send to PHP is too large, the data can be received, while I cannot get the variable using $_POST

Tags: php, post

Actually, I wanna send a high resolution image to PHP. I'm sure that the data have been captured, because when I use

`$img=file_get_contents("php://input");
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile,$img);
fclose($myfile);`

I can see data in *test.txt* file. And the *test.txt* file looks like the bellowing one:
[image]

No matter the size of my image, I can get the data I want in *test.txt*.
Everything is fine when image's size is in a normal range like 2MB, and I can save the image locally.  But the problem is when my image is too large nothing can be gotten. I use `$_POST` in PHP like bellowing.

`$img = $_POST["hidden_data"];
$board_company = $_POST["cbname"];`

Is it because the data is so large that PHP does not have the ability to find anything?  It's weird.

**EDIT1:**

Should I always save data as txt and then get what I what from the txt file? It's a little stupid. 
Incidentally, I have modified `post_max_size=100M`.

Comment: Maybe related: [What is the size limit of a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request)

Comment: @Mikey Thanks for your help~ But I think I can post all data to PHP because I can write all data in **.txt** file, the problem is on PHP's side I believe. Additionally, I have already set `post_max_size = 100M`. Still thank you~