# Is there a Character limit on form Post method?

Tags: html, forms, post, action

I have a form (mocked up in the snippet with test data for public consumption) and users will fill it out and hit "submit" which generates an email (we're using Outlook if that matters).

I'm running into an issue where, if some of the longer responses are chosen from the drop down menus, it cuts off the bottom of email (I think).

The "real world" html is on another network and I can't transfer it easily - but in the re-creation/snippet below, it will generate the email if the "long" response is chosen for up the 6 or 7th question. Any more than that it just doesn't launch Outlook and build the email, as if I have hit a limit of some kind.

In the "real world" version, the email **WILL** build....but it cuts off information from the bottom of the email.

This is just a local html file I use for office productivity - i.e. no server.

```html
<form style="width:300px" id="emailform" action="mailto:test@email.com?subject=TestSubject" method="post" enctype="text/plain">


  <p> Question 1<br><select required type='text' name='Question 1'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 2<br><select required type='text' name='Question 2'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 3<br><select required type='text' name='Question 3'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 4<br><select required type='text' name='Question 4'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 5<br><select required type='text' name='Question 5'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 6<br><select required type='text' name='Question 6'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 7<br><select required type='text' name='Question 7'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 8<br><select required type='text' name='Question 8'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 9<br><select required type='text' name='Question 9'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 10<br><select required type='text' name='Question 10'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 11<br><select required type='text' name='Question 11'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 12<br><select required type='text' name='Question 12'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 13<br><select required type='text' name='Question 13'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 14<br><select required type='text' name='Question 14'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 15<br><select required type='text' name='Question 15'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 16<br><select required type='text' name='Question 16'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 17<br><select required type='text' name='Question 17'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 18<br><select required type='text' name='Question 18'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 19<br><select required type='text' name='Question 19'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>
  <p> Question 20<br><select required type='text' name='Question 20'> <option value='SHORTOPTION'>SHORT OPTION</option><option value='LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION '>LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION LONG OPTION </option></select>    
  </p>

  <br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate Email">

</form>
```

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request

Comment: To answer, YES there is a POST limit which is set at the server level often times in the `post_max_size` parameter. Check this for more details: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: Thanks @Adam. I had read that...but the accepted answer "It depends on a server configuration" and offers a server side configuration...which I do not have. I'm pretty new to this - so maybe I'm missing the piece that I could use in that response?

Comment: On second thought, if you aren't getting any server level errors when you submit the form, it might not be related to `post_max_size` as PHP will usually bark at you when one of the .ini settings thresholds are reached. How many characters are we talking, roughly, in the email?

Comment: Looks like it cuts off around 1300 characters.

Comment: EDIT: Cut off is exactly 1469 characters...one more and it cuts off

Comment: Your example above s not valid html - </select> tag before </option> tag.

Comment: @Poul Bak html fixed, but I don't think this affects the issue at hand?