# Laravel: Input array returning only 995 values in post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

Its very strange, i can't understand why this happening. In laravel blade i just created a `select` with dynamic name like:

```
@foreach($chargesHeads->procedureList as $k => $charges)
     <tr class="single-row">
        <td width="320">{{ $charges->charges_title }}</td>
        <td width="85">
           {!! Form::select('unit['.$index.']',array_keys(array_fill(0,50,10)),@$unitData[$charges->id],['class'=>'form-control single-unit','style'=>'width:50px','data-charges'=>$charges->charges]) !!}
        </td>
        <td>{{ $charges->charges }}</td>
        <td>
            <span class="total_charges"></span>
        </td>
     </tr>
     @php
        $index++;
     @endphp
@endforeach
```

its generating multiple select very well. Its drawing index arround `1290` but when i am submitting the form i am only receiving `995` records only:

[image]

can any one tell me where i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638477/max-size-of-a-php-post

Comment: i don't think so, it should not truncate the data

Comment: i just update the post size 8mb to 800mb, still same problem

Comment: You missed to read this answer in the question above on `max_input_vars` (default 1000) :https://stackoverflow.com/a/12741046/3392344

Comment: yes i also update this, same prob

Comment: Did you change also `memory_limit` and restarted the server?

Comment: yes you were right, i updated the MAMP php.ini file and its working fine when i am working on the url: `http://localhost/project/public` but not with `php artisan serve` even php.ini file updated confirmed