# Using jQuery to send very long string PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to send very long string (about 1 200 000 chars) from my jQuery script to PHP server. 
I created code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'con.php',
    async : false,
    type : 'POST',
    data : 'require='+parameters
}).done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

where `parameters` is describing string
and in PHP:

```
if ($_POST['require']){
echo 'ok';
}
```

When I'm sending normal-size string everything is good, but when I sent my big string I got the error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: require
```

I setup `memory_limit` in my php.ini to 500M and still get nothing.

I tried to use `[suhosin][1]` with setting up `suhosin.memory_limit` greater than 0 with same results as above.

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: split your string in smaller chunks and serialize them in a json object

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request

Comment: `sync` calls are bad.

Comment: what about php's post max size?

Comment: `post_max_size 20M` will help you.. see these question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276759/php-whats-the-total-length-of-a-post-global-variable

Answer (score 1):

Try having your data sent like this:

```
data: {
    require: parameters
}
```

and set your php max post sizes:

```
post_max_size=20M
upload_max_filesize=20M
```