# Failed to load response data

Tags: php, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm working with angular in the front side and php in back and the request of getting a list of objects seems to fail each time the list is under 10Mb and the navigator shows a message "Failed to load response data" in the answer part of the request,
I don't know if it's due to some configurations in php.ini or the navigator (chrome)

Comment: how would the response data look like?

Comment: it's a list of objets, and each object contains JSON fields and metadata

Comment: Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Comment: Can you please post an example? What does the console and the details tab in Chrome say? Did you try to send a smaller response? What is the return code (404 or something else)?

Comment: The code you use for the AJAX would be helpful https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/83 https://github.com/martyjs/marty/issues/90 https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=453078 Is the data actually loaded or not?

Comment: the data is loaded in the app interface but this heavy data makes debugging response difficult and when I try to display an object, chrome crashs,
ex: getting the list of books, each object contains 100 fiels and each field contains a long text, when I try to display a book chrome crashs

Comment: try to send less data for debugging purposes and try streaming and caching the data

Comment: Well I tried to generate a string and increase its size, the message 'failed to load response data..' appears when I go under 9Mb of response data

Comment: This makes generally no sense. And why so much data at once instead of streaming (eg with Oboe.js) it? Did you try Google Chrome Canary?

Comment: if you debug the PHP code, you should get some info and inspect the information from phpinfo() so check the settings of your server and PHP runtime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276759/php-whats-the-total-length-of-a-post-global-variable